# Magento 2 Configuration add Enabled Or Disable extension option

Tags: magento2, extensions, configuration

I would like to add option in Configuration for module Enabled Yes/No.

I have tried below code but not working. Can you please suggest me any change on it or need to add any anther file.

```
<field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
        <label>Enabled</label>
        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
</field>
```

Comment: any error you face?

Comment: Not any Error,  Just  I put Code in syste.xml file and in Configuration I have set No . Still module data show into front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in your layout when phtml called 
use ifconfig="sectionid/groupid/fieldid" like this

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="vendorname_Modulename::your.phtml" ifconfig="sectionid/groupid/fieldid"/>
```

You can check module enable or disable in controller,block

```
<?php
namespace Companyname\Modulename\Controller\ControllerFolder;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    private $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {

        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $enableConfig = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('sectionid/groupid/sectionid', $storeScope);
        if ($enableConfig) {
            $this->_view->loadLayout();
            $this->_view->renderLayout();
        } else {
            $this->_redirect('404');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ans, This is also useful for my other question . But This is not useful for module disable. When I select No module is not showing in front-end like URL go with 404.

Comment: @HiteshVaghasiya i have update answer check it